# soapui rest multipart content + json

Tags: json, rest, soapui, multipartform-data, multipart

I have rest service which accepts multipart data in meaning of file/content and metadata/json. When I'm testing it with curl everything works perfectly:
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/upload/multi -F "file=@/tmp/1.csv" -F "meta-data={\"key\":\"test\"};type=application/json"`

But now testers need to test this within soapui and I can't get it to work. Attaching file is not problem. Problem is meta-data part at it seems to be sent as `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii"` but I need it to be sent as application/json. Is there way how to setup this? Or does anybody have working solution how to send content + meta-data from within SoapUI?

[image]